# Blend4Web not detected in Blender 2.8.3

Tags: game-engine, add-on, blend4web

I have a simple question concerning the installation of Blend4Web on Blender 2.8.3.
I add the path of the Blend4Web add-on to Blender, but I cannot find the add-on, nor can I found a engine window that would allow me to choose the add-on, if activated.

Is this an issue of this particular Blender version? Should I install an older version to be able to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, per [this discussion thread](https://www.blend4web.com/en/forums/topic/4697/) at the Blend4Web website, it would appear that the latest version of Blender that supports Blend4Web would be 2.79, so the answer to your question would be "Not yet supported, unless you install and use Blender 2.79 for that specific purpose."

On the bright side, there's nothing at all preventing you from using older versions of Blender on the same system as a newer version of Blender, and the Blend4Web folks kindly host a download of Blender 2.79 on [their downloads page](https://www.blend4web.com/en/downloads/) for your convenience, and I do believe that you can still find older versions of Blender on the [official Blender website](https://blender.org) if you look around a bit.

Edit: Just thought I would add the warning that if you should choose to go the route of using older versions of Blender alongside newer versions, be sure to keep the project files for each separate from one another as newer `.blend` files may not load happily in older versions of Blender, and mixing/matching project files between versions of Blender **could** result in corrupted or unusable files, requiring you to jump through some hoops to recover your project data.

Comment: I have installed 2.79 as well. I try to export a game to *html files, but it seems that I should do some extra work... Should I develop the whole game with Blend4Web? Can I also export to *exe in this way? Can I add website codes to the export *html file, to make the game embedded in a website? Thanks!

Comment: @Eden : I am sorry, but I don't actually use (or even try to use) Blend4Web anymore, so I've kinda forgotten most everything I knew about it.  Lately I've become enamored with https://godotengine.org/ and been using that pretty much exclusively for everything I export from Blender.  It does support web export, as well as import from newer versions of Blender, so it might be worth a try for your needs as well perhaps?

Comment: Thank you, anyway. I have moved to Godot, too. Things work there!

Comment: @Eden : Aye, that's been my experience with Godot as well.  I only wish I'd tried it sooner.  Turns out it's an excellent little game engine.  :)

Comment: I totally agree!